# How can stop foreach duplicate values in smarty 2?

Tags: foreach, smarty

I have this results after foreach on the template. But how can stop foreaching the same values and show only one?

```
<ul>
{foreach from=$names item=v name=thenames}
    <li>{$v.names}/<li>
{/foreach}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a simple key->value array, you can use [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) in your php file to process the array  before sending it to smarty. You also probably can call it inside the template with $names|array_unique

If all the duplicates are one after another (i.e. a,a,a,b,b,c,c,c), you can try using a variable to store the previous value, so it only shows the first:

```
{assign var="previous" value=""}
{foreach from=$names item=v name=thenames}
    {if $previous!=$v.names}
    <li>{$v.names}/<li>
    {/if}
    {assign var="previous" value=$v.names}
{/foreach}
```

If not, I recommend preprocessing the array in php or using smarty 3.

Comment: I need to use it in the template. No this way is not working for me i using smarty 2 if that is problem

Comment: Can you post the original template code inside the {foreach}?